# $("#Name").autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I run this page I see error in firebug

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = '/Tag/TagName';
$('#Name').autocomplete(url, {
minChars: 1,
multiple: true,
formatResult: function (row) {
return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
}
}).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
alert(!data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
});
})
</script>
```

Error is:

```
$("#Name").autocomplete is not a function
```

Also I have in this document

```
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) 
        </div>
```

What is the source of this error?

Best regards

**EDIT**

Non, is

```
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I have another error:

```
$("#Name").autocomplete(url, {minChars: 1, multiple: true, formatResult: function (row) {return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, "");}}).result is not a function
```

If this can help:

every script library binding I have at _Layout.cshtml

_Layout.cshtml

Comment: 2 things, 1.) do you have jQuery UI loaded on this page? (you'll need it in order to call .autocomplete(...) and 2.) by `$("#Name")` I take it "Name" is actually the `ID` of the element you want, since the # (hash) notation is for finding elements by ID, not by Name. e.g. it should be `$("#id")`

Comment: 2) Id and name of this input are Name, so there is no problem with this. 1)  yes, now (after @Jon answer) I have : <script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")"

Answer (score 5):

The direct reason is that you don't load the jQuery autocomplete plugin (the error message is pretty clear on that).

The underlying reason is that you are missing the opening quote after `src=`:

```
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")"
```

Comment: Ok, you have right, but now I get error: $("#Name").autocomplete(url, {minChars: 1, multiple: true, formatResult: function (row) {return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, "");}}).result is not a function

Comment: @user278618: That's because there is no `result` member as the error message tells you. Where did you get this code?

Comment: @Jon from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401594/problem-with-delimitir-using-jquery-and-mvc-razor/6401682#6401682

Comment: @Jon  - so what I need to change to get this code working? I can delete this alert  - is not necessary. If you post at upon question answer I'll give you bounty :)

Comment: @user278612: I 'm sorry, but I can't research this right now. Will get back to you later.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you are including the jQuery Autocomplete plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Edit: There is an autocomplete function included with jQuery UI, which is what you are using here. This function is not the same as the jQuery Autocomplete plugin. It does not work the same way. The code you are using here is referencing that plugin, but the autocomplete function you are calling is the one included with jQuery UI. You should take a look at the jQuery UI autocomplete and if that is not what you need you can include the jQuery Autocomplete plugin script and use that instead, keeping your existing code. Be sure to add the plugin script file after jQuery UI so it doesn't get overwritten or download a new version of jQuery UI with the autocomplete function removed.

**jQuery UI Autocomplete**
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

**jQuery Autocomplete plugin**
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

**Example of jQuery UI plugin in action**

```
$( "#Name" ).autocomplete({
    source: url,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Did you link the library?:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added it and : $("#Name").autocomplete(url, {minChars: 1, multiple: true, formatResult: function (row) {return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, "");}}).result is not a function

Comment: you can find a complex example here:  http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/     (just view the source, maybe something else needs to be added.). Also check your jQuery version (did you link it too ?)

Comment: I've have a default asp.net MVC 3 template with jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js jquery-1.5.1.js jquery-1.5.1.min.js jquery-ui-1.8.11.js and jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js libraries

Comment: thank for the link, but I'm to newbie to get something from that